# Running python in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have an `Applicant` model containing `title`, `first_name` and `surname` and I am passing a list of them to a template here:

```
 {% for applicant in applicants %}
   <tr>
     <td>{{ applicant.id }}</td>
     <td>{{ applicant.title.replace('^','') }} {{ applicant.first_name }} {{ ed {% 
   </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

The problem is that the titles contain dodgy characters (`^`) that I need to replace in python

```
applicant.title.replace('^','')
```

But this causes the template to break

```
Could not parse the remainder: '('^','')' from 'applicant.title.replace('^','')'
```

How can I run python on a template variable without causing this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this simple case, you can use the builtin `cut` filter like so:

```
<td>{{ applicant.title|cut:"^" }} ...
```

If you need something more complicated, you could write a [Custom Template Filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/).

`cut`, for example, is implemented like this:

```
def cut(value, arg):
    """Removes all values of arg from the given string"""
    return value.replace(arg, '')
```

you could easily implement something like:

```
def myfilter(value):
    """sanitizes my output"""
    for c in "_^/\\":
        value = value.replace(c, '')
    return value
```

and apply with

```
<td>{{ applicant.title|myfilter }} ...
```

Comment: there's already such a template filter builtin : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#cut

Answer (score 0):

> How can I run python on a template variable without causing this error?

You can't, at least not without switching to a different template processor.

With Django, you are supposed to perform all of your data transformations in the view. The template is only for final rendering of the html.

What you can do is use a different templating engine (jinja2 is a popular choice), and use the output of that as the content of your response.

Comment: "With Django, you are supposed to perform all of your data transformations in the view." : this is just false. Django's template system comes with a comprehensive set of template tags and filters (that can perform "data transformations" and more) and you can add your own tags and filters.